# How do I find the device node file for a USB device in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I've bought an X10 Home Automation USB interface: the CM15.

This is the information lsusb gives:

```
skerit@KIP-DU-SKER:~$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bc7:0001 X10 Wireless Technology, Inc. ActiveHome (ACPI-compliant)
```

But this tells me nothing about where the device file is! How can I find that, or create one myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Device nodes are created by the kernel automatically (or by udev in older distributions). Udev also creates descriptive links under `/dev/disk/by-*/` and similar.

If it's a storage device, **`lsblk -f`** or **`sudo blkid`** should list it.

Serial devices are usually `ttyUSBnum` or `ttyACMnum`.

For everything else, check the system log in **`dmesg`**.

Answer (score 0):

Typing

##### `udevadm monitor`

or
`udevadm monitor --property`  (more detailed device properties of event)
into a terminal window and let visible while inserting a usb device, will print debug messages for device path and included driver class and drivers for that device.

Example output for wlan device:

> UDEV  [4673693.744066] add /devices/platform/soc/.../net/wlan0 (net)
> ACTION=
> DEVPATH=
> SUBSYSTEM=
> DEVTYPE=
> INTERFACE=
> IFINDEX=
> SEQNUM=
> USEC_INITIALIZED=
> ID_MM_CANDIDATE=
> ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=
> ID_NET_NAME_MAC=
> ID_VENDOR=
> ID_VENDOR_ENC=
> ID_VENDOR_ID=
> ID_MODEL=
> ID_MODEL_ENC=
> ID_MODEL_ID=
> ID_REVISION=
> ID_SERIAL=
> ID_SERIAL_SHORT=
> ID_TYPE=
> ID_BUS=
> ID_USB_INTERFACES=
> ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=
> ID_USB_DRIVER=
> ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=
> ID_PATH=
> ID_PATH_TAG=
> ID_NET_DRIVER=
> ID_NET_LINK_FILE=
> ID_NET_NAME=
> SYSTEMD_ALIAS=
> ID_RENAMING=
> INTERFACE_OLD=
> TAGS=
> CURRENT_TAGS=

Having a <device path>

> /sys/devices/platform/soc.../net/wlan0

will help finding attributes

##### `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=<device path>`

for writing a udev rule, that can create a /dev directory node for that device.

Example for udev rule (e.g. /etc/udev/rules.d/[<number>-<device>.rules](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html))

> KERNEL=="wlan*", DRIVERS=="cm15a", ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bc7", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", NAME="wlan%n", SYMLINK+="%k%n"